# PHP Compare specific characters betwen two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, compare, character, specifications

In PHP, I have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:26-DOWN
    [1] => 09:26-UP
    [2] => 09:26-UP
    [3] => 09:26-UP
    [4] => 09:26-UP
    [5] => 09:26-UP
    [6] => 09:26-UP
    [7] => 09:26-UP
    [8] => 09:26-DOWN
    [9] => 09:26-UP
    [10] => 09:26-UP
    [11] => 09:26-UP
    [12] => 09:26-UP
    [13] => 09:26-UP
    [14] => 09:26-UP
    [15] => 09:26-UP
    [16] => 09:26-UP
    [17] => 09:26-UP
)
```

and I want to compare it with below array, only with the last characters (UP and DOWN):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:31-DOWN
    [1] => 09:31-UP
    [2] => 09:31-UP
    [3] => 09:31-UP
    [4] => 09:31-UP
    [5] => 09:31-UP
    [6] => 09:31-UP
    [7] => 09:31-UP
    [8] => 09:31-UP
    [9] => 09:31-UP
    [10] => 09:31-UP
    [11] => 09:31-UP
    [12] => 09:31-UP
    [13] => 09:31-UP
    [14] => 09:31-UP
    [15] => 09:31-UP
    [16] => 09:31-UP
    [17] => 09:31-UP
)
```

So the purpose is to check if it up or down between the specific time.

Comment: so what happens in the end?

Comment: @MarkM I want to compare the array. Let say compare only the last characters of the array.

Comment: What do you expect when the `$array1[0]` is 'UP' and the `$array2[0]` is 'DOWN' ? UP to DOWN = DOWN, UP to UP = no change, DOWN to UP = UP, DOWN to DOWN = no change ?

Comment: @Ghost If the values are different, than I want to send the value to the email. And if the value are the same, then do nothing.

Comment: @PrabowoMurti that's right, look like you got my question. But it hard to explain :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but here's a simple option. Assuming that the format of each element will always be the same, ie `HH:II-[UP or DOWN]`, you could do this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    $result[] = $v[6] . $arr2[$k][6];
}
```

Given your two arrays, `$arr1` and `$arr2`, this will yield a third array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DD
    [1] => UU
    [2] => UU
    [3] => UU
    [4] => UU
    ....
)
```

Then you can use this array's values, `UU`, `DD`, `UD`, `DU`, to figure out what is in each position. For example key 3 will have `UU`, so you know it is UP, UP....

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/PuIDsBSI)

---

***Update*** Here's the one-liner version using [**array_map()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){return $a[6] . $b[6];}, $arr1, $arr2);
```

[**See demo 2**](http://3v4l.org/FhRJa)

Comment: +1 for less string processing function calls. Generally faster than my answer.

Comment: @MarkM Thank you for the fast answer, I got it working now :)

Comment: @bluewolf Glad to help! PS see my recent update for the one-line solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) + [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) to cut apart state / status.

```
$changed = []; // to store changed statuses

foreach($old as $i => $value){
    $from = trim(strstr($value, '-'), '-');   // getting status (UP / DOWN) from first array
    $to   = trim(strstr($new[$i], '-'), '-'); // getting status (UP / DOWN) from second array

    if($from != $to){ // if statuses are different
        $changed[$i] = [
            'from' => $from,
            'to'   => $to
        ]; // add to changed array
    }
}
```

***Full example:***

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$old = [
    '09:26-DOWN',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-DOWN',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP',
    '09:26-UP'
];

$new = [
    '09:31-DOWN',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP',
    '09:31-UP'
];

$changed = [];

foreach($old as $i => $value){
    $from = trim(strstr($value, '-'), '-');
    $to   = trim(strstr($new[$i], '-'), '-');

    if($from != $to){
        $changed[$i] = [
            'from' => $from,
            'to'   => $to
        ];
    }
}

print_r($changed);
?>
```

***Output:***

```
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [from] => DOWN
            [to] => UP
        )

)
```

Comment: @bluewolf Good luck with your tasks. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Give the two arrays

```
<?php 

$array1 = array('UP', 'DOWN', 'UP', 'DOWN');
$array2 = array('UP', 'DOWN', 'DOWN', 'UP');

foreach ($array2 as $key => $new_value)
{
    $old_value = $array1[$key];
    $new_array[$key] = ($old_value <= $new_value ? (($old_value < $new_value) ? 'UP' : 'NO CHANGE') : 'DOWN');
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Will output something like this

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "NO CHANGE"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "NO CHANGE"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "DOWN"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "UP"
}
```